# Get URL for embedded image on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, request, embed

I have created a certification platform and whenever a user gets a certification he/she gets a badge image link to add to his/her website.

When they do that I generate the image on my server-side. So, if they add the image url `http://mycertification.com/badges/asdfasdfasdfasdf.jpg`, it will check on my side if the image has been created and return it or, if not, create a new one.

I have now over 10000 certified users and I would like to check if they are embedding the badges and also where the badges are embedded. So, if the user from the website www.user1.com embeds the badge image on this website, I would like to track that.

I have created a model `BadgeTracker` with the `user_id`, the `url` and a `counter`. Simple as that. The counter works already, now I want to know the URL where the image is embedded!

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: So you want to check to see if you already have an image with the exact same url? It should be something like `BadgeTracker.where(url: new_url)`, where `new_url` is the url of the image you are uploading currently.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to verify if the certified users actually embedded the image on their own website ?

Comment: Yes Laurens... and which website have they embedded on... but I have already found out that this would only be possible by adding some javascript code to the embbed code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to track if the user put the embed code on their website. You could only track how many times the badge has been viewed (meaning loaded) in a browser. If this is the case then you may create a route that handles badge displaying, so once the browser tries to access this URL you collect the badge information from the params, save it in the DB and then simply return the badge image. Sorry if I got your question wrong...
If you're interested I could try to create a code snippet with the solution.

Comment: I have already done this solution myself and realized it is impossible to track down the embedded url from the image embedding itself unless I add a JS code to the embedding  code in order to get the url. But thank you!